# Mutex для двух массивов

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть два массива:

```
char a[10];
char b[10];
```

Если вносить изменения в эти массивы из разных потоков, то надо объявить каждому массиву mutex?
Если делать так, то это будет правильно?

```
char a[10];
mutex a_mutex;
char b[10];
mutex b_mutex;
```

А в потоках их блокировать и разблокировать для записи? Так:

```
(*a_mutex).lock();
(*a)[2] = 'w';
(*a_mutex).unlock();
```

Comment: Если это два независимых массива, то да, решение выше близко к истине. Если нужно ещё модифицировать два массива одновременно постоянно и обеспечить правильное согласованное состояние, тогда правильно будет завести один мютекс на два массива.

Comment: Да это два независимых массива, и данные вносятся потоком или в один, или в другой. А для чтения массива в потоке обязательно использовать .lock();.unlock(); ?

Comment: @eagl69, использование lock/unlock завист исключительно от *логики* задачи.

Вы о смысле задачи вообще ничего не написали. В принципе, вполне допустима ситуация, когда элементарные данные в массиве изменяются разными потоками вообще без всякой синхронизации.

Comment: Логика простая, по событию один из потоков вносит изменения в массив, а другие в это время по необходимости просматривают его, поэтому для записи мы блокируем, чтобы просмотр массива был только после его изменения, а вот для чтения, я так понял, не обязательно?

Comment: на самом деле можно даже не блокировать для записи. Оно будет работать. Другое дело, какой будет результат.

Теоретически, запись int на современных системах - атомарная запись. Поэтому, если элементы в массиве "независимы", то можно теоретически не блокировать. Но если записи хоть как то связаны - блокировка нужна.

Comment: а если получится, что один читает, а другой в это время записывает в ту же ячейку памяти? Мы прочитаем результат до, после записи или вообще что попало?

Comment: @KoVadim: на многопроцессорной неинтеловской системе чтение без блокировки после записи под блокировкой может считать stale value. (пруф, например, [тут](https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http://twvideo01.ubm-us.net/o1/vault/gdc09/slides/GDC09_Dawson_Lockless_Programming.ppt) на 25-ом слайде).

Comment: @VladD, а при чем здесь блокировки мьютекса? 

Каким это образом компилятор может связать мьютекс с данными, доступ к которым им логически разделяется? Когда компилятор знает (обычно это всякие модификаторы, типа volatile), он может использовать команды аппаратной синхронизации (если они есть в архитектуре). 

А для мьютекса все это может относиться   только к данным самого мьютекса (кстати, тоже важно).

--

(А ссылка не работает, указывает на текущий вопрос. Видимо, что-то не так с редактором на ХК).

Comment: @eagl69, говоря "вообще что попало", Вы подразумеваете вообще любую мешанину из битиков?

Конечно нет. Прочтем или старые данные или уже обновленные (но ни коим образом не их смесь).

И понятие одновременности  для многих современных многоядерных систем не очень-то определяется.

Единственно, что можно определенно сказать, что если один поток пишет в память, а другой ее же читает, то рано или поздно читатель будет видеть изменения, которые делает писатель (но не все). 

А Вы просто поэкспериментируйте. Один поток пишет for (i = 0; ... i++)... Другой выводит в файл if ((newval = i) != oldval).

Comment: @avp: И правда, вот сокращённая ссылка: http://bit.ly/1yMZRBd

Компилятор не связывает мьютекс с данными, но ставит двусторонний memory barrier на получении и отпускании, т. е. процессор не имеет права задерживать запись/чтение. (Это с низкоуровневой точки зрения.) А вот volatile этому помочь [не может](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c-and-the-perils-of-double-checked-locki/184405772), по идее.